# Why is it that when I upload a base64 image to firebase it shows in storage with extension application/octet

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Basically, I have a base64 image that I want to upload to firebase storage but whenever I do that, it ends up having a "application/octet" extension which is not what i was expecting, where am I going wrong?

The Function handling the upload to firebase storage

```
const handleFiles = (files) => {
    if(files == null) return;

    const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/${v4()}`);
    //Upload image to firebase
    uploadBytes(imageRef, files.base64.slice(23)).then(() => {
      alert("Image Uploaded")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files),

> If no `contentType` metadata is specified and the file doesn't have a file extension, Cloud Storage defaults to the type `application/octet-stream`. Also, try using `uploadString()` to upload `base64` strings instead of `uploadBytes()`

Try specifing the `contentType` of your file as shown below:

```
uploadString(imageRef, files.base64.slice(23), 'base64', {
  contentType: 'image/png', // <-- replace with file's type
}).then(() => {
  alert('Image Uploaded')
})
```

Comment: I got a "Error loading preview" on the firebase storage, I also noticed that the file size is just 9bytes on the storage

Comment: @HadiZouhbi it's seems you just have `undefined` being uploaded? Can you `console.log(image)` in your code and share a screenshot of the output? Does it have a base64 property?

Comment: It says image is not defined, I have not stored the image in a variable though , the image is the files.base64.slice(23)

Comment: @HadiZouhbi my bad, can you `console.log(files)` and share output of that?

Comment: `{name: 'dinner_buffet.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg', size: '55 kB', base64: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD…IyPNPzVG33qKK0MyOV2/vGq0sjf3jRRQAsTtn7xooorMD/9k=', file: File}`

Comment: @HadiZouhbi can you try using `uploadString()` instead of `uploadBytes` as in my updated answer? There are 4 params in the function now.